# Exception while setting property in subclass of MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, properties, mkmapview, subclass

I got a strange error. After I installed my test app in release mode I got an error:

```
[SomeMapView setRotateEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c58ac40
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SomeMapView setRotateEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c58ac40'
```

The Mapview was initialized and in the init method I was trying to deactivate the rotation. In the debugging mode it worked fine.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setRotateEnabled:FALSE];

        [self initDelegate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Maybe someone knows what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS your device is running? rotateEnabled is available only in iOS7.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. I changed the test device and problem occures in IOS6. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in the iOS version. RotateEnabled in available only in iOS7 like Suresh point out. I had to check if the property was there (or check if it has iOS7) like

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(elementName)]) 
{
    [self setValue:elementInnerText forKey:elementName];
}
```